# Unsure of "return type defaults to 'int', and undefined references to ‘main’ and `read_from_net' errors"

Tags: c

So I'm not into coding C at all, for a job I'm interviewing for (not a programmer role) they'd like me to fix this code. I did tell them I couldn't code in C but they insisted that I should be able to find the answer with some research. I've spent a few hours reading various articles and looking at the errors a compiler throws up. But in all honesty I don't understand 90% of contents of these articles or what the errors even really mean.

So far the answer I have is this: "Linker errors, Undefined references to ‘main’ and `read_from_net'. Implicit declaration of function error." But I'm not sure if that's just because it's just an extract of a larger piece of code that I'm missing required parts of.

```
f() {
        char buf[80], *p = buf;
        while ((*p = read_from_net()) != '\0') {
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, as I'm not really sure I can learn to code in C in a few days, enough to see the errors.

Many thanks

Comment: This assignment makes no sense to me, and we can't teach you enough C here for you to solve it.

Comment: @Barmar It must be a special workplace. :-) Hired to do one thing and asked to solve problems in an unrelated field. Perhaps it's the new "everyone should be able to do everything" thingy - in which case, people shouldn't be hired for a certain position, just "work".

Comment: @TedLyngmo This is what I mean by I'm not sure if stuff is missing as this extract of code is all I have to work off. I'm not sure if defintions would be above in a larger piece of code or if this is standalone?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It seems like it's seeing how good he is at doing research in new areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. f() {
2.    char buf[80], *p = buf;
3.    while ((*p = read_from_net()) != '\0') {
4.    }
5. }
```

with output from one of the common compilers:

```
source>:1:1: error: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    1 | f() {
      | ^
<source>: In function 'f':
<source>:3:18: error: implicit declaration of function 'read_from_net' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    3 |     while ((*p = read_from_net()) != '\0') {
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    5 | }
```

- 1. In C every function declaration must include the *type* of the value the function will return. If the function doesn't return a value at all, it should be declared (to return) `void`. `f()` lacks this information and according to ancient rules this would mean that the declaration defaulted to returning an `int`, an integer. This implicit declaration is not required to work anymore according to the C standard (since C99 I believe).
- 3. A call is made to a function for which no declaration has been seen by the compiler. In earlier days, this would slip through as an implicit function declaration and the compiler would assume that the function return `int` (the default again). This does however not match the type the return value is assigned to. `p` is a `char*` which makes dereferencing `p` (`*p`) a `char` - so, the declaration `char read_from_net();` should be found somewhere and an `#include <file_that_declares_read_from_net.h>` should be added to the top of the file.
- 5. Since the compiler chose `int` to be the return type for `f()` in `1.`, `f()` should `return` and `int` - but it doesn't. Control (the "executor of the program" if you will) leaves the scope of the function without returning anything. We can now go back to `1.` and realize that `f()` should have been `void f()` to fix that issue.

> "Linker errors, Undefined references to ‘main’ and `read_from_net'.

- `main` - This is the start of every standard C program. It's a function with the declaration `int main(void);` or `int main(int, char**);` (with some platform specfic extras). Without this function a compiled program wouldn't know which function to call first. Now, you can have `C` files without `main`. It's just that when all the `C` files that makes up a program are compiled and **linked** together, one (and only one) of them must have this `main` function.
- `read_from_net` - It seems that you've missed to link with the library that defines the function `read_from_net`. So, not only do you need `#include <file_that_declares_char_read_from_net.h>`, you also need to link your final executable (the program you'll finally run) with a library or object file that contains this function.

```
#include <file_that_declares_read_from_net.h>

void f() {
    char buf[80], *p = buf;
    while ((*p = read_from_net()) != '\0') {
        ++p; // some progress of p is probably wanted
        // note: p may go out of bounds if `\0` is not found within 80 chars
    }
}

int main() {
     // does something and probably calls f()
}
```

and compilation could look like this:

```
compiler -o program.exe your_program.c file_that_defines_read_from_net.o
```

Comment: I can confirm that the implicit return types went away from C89->C99, and it's [covered on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration) (right above the "Defect Reports" section).

Comment: `void f()` and `int main()` are also declared using old rules; they are not prototypes; it would be better `void f(void)` and `int main(void)`, then it's an error calling them with parameters.

Comment: @Neil Very true. I'm looking forward to C23 when that will no longer be the case. Finally, `void f()` and `int main()` will mean functions that takes no parameters.

Comment: @Neil Take it with a grain of salt... I was so sure about that just a second ago but now I can't remember if I saw it in the [C2x draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2912.pdf) or if I got inspired by a compiler error message :-D

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not sure that's a good thing or bad thing; on the one hand, implicit function rules are useless and should never have been there, but on the other, it creates two ways to express it, one of which is new and a different meaning from before. It will be interesting to see how they do it.

Comment: @Neil Interesting indeed. I thought that I knew a bit of C since I worked with it a lot in the late 80's and early 90's but I have since been "gone". Now that I'm reacquainting myself a bit with it here on SO, I realize that I've have missed a great deal of progress - and that many of my old "that's just how it works"es haven't actually worked that way at all. I was just lucky. I think all my ~1990 programs would have a fat UB stamp on them. One of them could even still be running - which is also a possible outcome of UB I guess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some fixes explained with comments below

```
int f(void)                                     // Function f takes no parameters (void), and returns an integer
{
    char buf[80], *p = buf;
    while ((*p++ = read_fron_net()) != '\0') {  // Increment p every time a character is read by using p++
    }

    return p-buff;                              // Return the number of characters read.
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. Would it be possible for you to explain in laymans terms as best as possible, what the errors you actually fixed were? And any other errors (the undefined references) that would remain?

Comment: Honestly, No.  A full understanding of this requires at least a College class in C programming, including the compiler, the linker, syntax, functions, stack, pointers, IO, buffers.  Its just too much to cover in a few messages on Stack Overflow.   Recommend you look for a different company, and pass on this one.